# The best way to have same module twice, while using T3JS framework

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I started working with T3js framework (https ://github.com/box/t3js) in order to keep my code structured and easy scalable.

I want to find out the right way to include the same module twice (or more times) in the same page without the ids to get messed up.

Take a look at the T3js documentation and examples and specifically at the TODOS example (http ://t3js.org/examples/todo/). What I want to do is something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjICt.png), but at the same time make sure that the ids are not messed up, and the instantiations of the module are independent.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/box/t3js/issues/180) j3tan explains how we can instanciate the same module multiple times in one html file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi me and my team worked on a project that has a dashboard and different tabs in it, in this case what we've done is we gave the parent div of the page a `data-module` to put there our public functions and some variables to be broadcoast to every child div or `data-module`, in this case we were able to call every (lets say widgets) by their `data-module` or (lets say by their tabs) this helped us to implement loose coupling to every modules since were using `context-broadcast` inorder to pass a parameter if ever we wish to.
Hope this has been helpful to you.